# Clever use of generics seems to compile in one Java version but does not in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I have some open source code I'm looking at.  The project compiles at the command line using mvn clean install.

The project gives the errors shown below when opened in Eclipse.

I'm thinking I have not set the Java compiler version correctly and Eclipse is using a different version of Java than I think it is.

Is this type of use of generics allowed in some versions of java but not in others?

The second call below compiles.

The first call below gives the compiler error below, but only in Eclipse, not when compiled using mvn clean install at the command line.

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<ValidatorGroup<T,?>> to List<ValidatorGroup<T,?>>   AbstractForEachValidatorBuilder.java    /WebAPI/src/main/java/org/ohdsi/webapi/check/builder    line 44 Java Problem
```

Note the change in return types from <U> List<U> to List<ValidatorGroup<T,?>>.

```
private List<ValidatorGroupBuilder<T, ?>> validatorGroupBuilders = new ArrayList<>();
private List<ValidatorBuilder<T>> validatorBuilders = new ArrayList<>();


protected List<ValidatorGroup<T,?>> initGroups() {
    return initAndBuildList(this.validatorGroupBuilders);
}

protected List<Validator<T>> initValidators() {
    return initAndBuildList(this.validatorBuilders);
}

private <U> List<U> initAndBuildList(List<? extends ValidatorBaseBuilder<T, U, ?>> builders) {

    //...do stuff
}
```

**The ValidatorBuild class**

```
public abstract class ValidatorBuilder<T> extends ValidatorBaseBuilder<T, Validator<T>, ValidatorBuilder<T>> {

    public abstract Validator<T> build();

}
```

**The ValidatorGroupBuilder class**

```
public class ValidatorGroupBuilder<T, V> extends ValidatorBaseBuilder<T, ValidatorGroup<T, V>, ValidatorGroupBuilder<T, V>> {
```

Full project is here: https://github.com/OHDSI/WebAPI

**--- EDIT ---------------------------**

**Here are the places where I've set the Java version to 1.8**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**From the pom.xml file**

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

**From the pom.xml file**

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
      <compilerArgs>
        <!-- Prevents recompilation due to missing package-info.class, see MCOMPILER-205 -->
        <arg>-Xpkginfo:always</arg>
      </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

**--- SECOND EDIT --------------------------------------**

Both the MVN build and the Eclipse build generate classes with major version of 52 (Java 8).

[image]

When I create a JUnit test and run it in my Eclipse environment it indicates a JRE of 1.8.0_261.

**--- THIRD EDIT -------------------------------------------**

A complete minimum example that gives this error is provided here:
https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/eclipse-compile-error-example

This project compiles with MVN

[image]

This project does not compile in Eclipse

[image]

This is the version of Eclipse I'm using

[image]

The issue is also seen in this version of Eclipse:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have the eclipse settings pointed at the right java language level?

Comment: Seems very likely that you are using two versions of javac

Comment: Eclipse uses its own compiler ("ecj") rather than javac so there are ocassionally differences from javac in what it thinks is valid.

Comment: Note: It doesn't matter what Installed JREs you tell Eclipse about, the compiler is always the internal ecj compiler - which can compile for any compliance level. This looks like it is a bug in either ecj or javac.

Comment: i can reproduce..looks like an ecj issue. A workaround: `public abstract class AbstractForEachValidatorBuilder<T, V, X> extends ValidatorBuilder<V> {

    private List<ValidatorGroupBuilder<T, X>> validatorGroupBuilders = new ArrayList<ValidatorGroupBuilder<T, X>>();

    protected List<ValidatorGroup<T,X>> initGroups() {
        return initAndBuildList(this.validatorGroupBuilders);
    } // as before` ?? (introducing type parameter `X` and replacing it (with first 3) occurrences of `?`)

Comment: @xerx593, Thanks! Your workaround saves the day... but doesn't explain why it compiles using mvn at the command line but does not compile in Eclipse. I've opened a bug in Eclipse's bugzilla for this.  I'll post here when I hear back from them.

Comment: "reproduce" doesn't mean understand :) ..but, very welcome! ..please transfer savings to .... xDxDxD, thank You for opening that issue! My "workaround" (of course) is a heavy intervention in your code! ...

Comment: But since there isn't even javadoc, ..and helped me (and apparently ecj) to "better structure the problem"..why not!? ;p

Comment: An important setting I missed in your screenshots is "Project>Build Automatically" (but it doesn't help much with the original issue...for this you'd had to prevent all "eclipse builds", but only use (maven)  "run configurations"... ;(